# Jackson change the key of a value without using annotation

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class A, with a property `Pojo p`.

```
class A {
   Pojo p;
}
```

I have a custom Serializer for Pojo, but I didn't find any way to change the key of Pojo, by default it's serialized as `p`.

Is there any way to change the key `p` to something else, like

```json
{
"some_other_key": {/* json for Pojo goes here*/}  
}
```

I can't use jackson annotations because this is a class from a lib.

```java
public class PojoSerializer extends StdSerializer<Pojo> {


  @Override
  public void serialize(Pojo pojo, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    //how can I set the key of this Pojo?
    jsonGenerator.writeObject(pojo);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, use jsonGenerator.

```
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("firstField", pojo.getFirstField());
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
```

You also need a custom serializer for A itself, not just "Pojo".

```
public class PojoSerializer extends StdSerializer<A> {


  public SaleBoSerializer(Class<A> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(A a, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("custom_field_name", a.pojo)
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
  }

}
```

Comment: hi, this would result in nesting the pojo to the next level.
{"p": { "custom_field_name": {...}}}
I somehow get this resolved by using an external MixIn class. but still welcome to new answers to do this without mixin.

Comment: No it would not—- this is a serializer for A, not Pojo

Comment: the problem is class A may have many other properties in real use cases. you would set all of them manually in your serialize method.

Comment: Fair point. if class A is within another library (i.e. you can't just use an annotation within class A), you will have that problem.